# Using $this when not in object context--i am using the latest version of php and mysql

Tags: php

This is user.php:

```
    include("databse.php");//retrieving successfully first name and lastname from databse file into user.php
    class user
    {
      public $first_name;
      public $last_name;
      public static function full_name()
      {
          if(isset($this->first_name) && isset($this->last_name))
          {
            return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;

          }
          else
           {
                return "";
           }
       }
    }
```

Other php file, index.php:

```
   include(databse.php);
   include(user.php);
    $record = user::find_by_id(1);
    $object = new user();
    $object->id = $record['id'];
    $object->username = $record['username'];
    $object->password = $record['password'];
    $object->first_name = $record['first_name'];
    $object->last_name = $record['last_name'];
    // echo   $object->full_name();
    echo $object->id;// successfully print the id
    echo $object->username;//success fully print the username
    echo->$object->full_name();//**ERROR:Using $this when not in object context**

?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant use `$this` in a static function. Use `self::` instead

Comment: thnks very much ...i really appreciate for you help

Answer (score 3):

Make `full_name` **non-static**:

```
public function full_name() {}
```

You cannot access instance variables from a static method but that is exactly what you are trying to do.

If you use `self` instead of `$this`, you have to declare `$first_name` and `$last_name` static as well.

I don't even understand *why* you declare this method as `static` in the first place. It is an instance method by all means.

Answer (score 0):

Check the last line of your index.php. `echo->$object->full_name()` is not valid. Use `echo $object->full_name()` instead.

Also, declare `full_name()` as non-static.